# C# search in text file

Tags: c#

Really new to C#. I need to search a text file for a keyword. If **after the whole file is searched**, the keyword is found pop a message box. If **after the whole file is searched**, the keyword is NOT found pop a message box.

So far I have this below. The problem is that it reads the file line by line. If in the first line the keyword is not found it shows the alert "Not found". Then goes to the next line and shows "Not found" again. And so on. I need the script to search the whole file, and only then show "Not found" only once. Thank you!

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
    String line;
    String[] array;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("keyword"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Keyword found!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Keyword not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So just read the entire file using [`ReadToEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: What have you tried? You could consider not showing a messagebox immediately, but keep the result in a variable that you check after the loop.

Comment: You should consider loading file and searching in them asynchronously (thread, threadpool, backgroundworker or better async/await mechanism).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File.ReadAllText is better suited for that, you can read in all the text at once in one string:

```
string file = File.ReadAllText("path");

if (file.Contains(keyword))     {
//..
}
else  {
//..
}
```

or in one line:

```
if (File.ReadAllText("path").Contains("path")) {
}
else {
}
```

Like stated in the comments, you can run out of memory for very large files but for normal day to day use this wont happen.

Comment: should be added that this is not suitable for large files

Comment: You're telling someone who just started programming _"use this code instead"_, without explaining _why_ they should use the code, nor what are the drawbacks of said code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `File` class instead of *readers* (which you have to `Dispose` in order to prevent resource leakage):

```
bool found = File
  .ReadLines("c:\\test.txt") // Try avoid "All" when reading: ReadAllText, ReadAllLines
  .Any(line => line.Contains("keyword")); 

if (found)
  MessageBox.Show("Keyword found!");
else 
  MessageBox.Show("Keyword not found!");
```

Your code amended (if you insist on `StreamReader`):

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Wra IDisposable (StreamReader) into using in order to prevent resource leakage 
  using (file = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt")) {
    string line;

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) 
      if (line.Contains("keyword")) {
        MessageBox.Show("Keyword found!");

        return; // Keyword found, reported and so we have nothing to do 
      } 
  }

  // File read with no positive result
  MessageBox.Show("Keyword not found!");
}
```